# Ubuntu Live CD doesn't boot properly

Tags: installation, 10.10, boot

I am using a Macbook Pro and just wanted to check out Ubuntu. I couldn't get a USB Flash drive for booting Ubuntu, so I decided to use a CD instead. I thought it was working fine, as it seemed to boot from the Live CD, but after the Ubuntu loading screen it just went into terminal, or whatever it uses. I.e., no GUI, etc..

It said something about not detecting drives?  Does anyone here know what I did wrong?  I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat).

Answer (score 1):

I was also once messed up into this kind of problem when I found out my CD drive combo is burnt up like a microwave oven and I could not plug in the USB  as the port were not fixed eiher.

Give Plop Boot Manager a try to according to which

> The boot manager has a built-in IDE CDROM and USB driver to access that hardware without the help/need of a BIOS.

Well, it worked for me in my case. You can give it a try.